# kubectl pull image from gitlab unauthorized: HTTP Basic: Access denied

Tags: kubernetes, google-compute-engine, gitlab-ci

I am trying to configure gitlab ci to deploy app to google compute engine. I have succesfully pushed image to gitlab repository but after applying kubernetes deployment config i see following error in kubectl describe pods:

```
Failed to pull image "registry.gitlab.com/proj/subproj/api:v1": rpc error: code = 2 
desc = Error response from daemon: {"message":"Get https://registry.gitlab.com/v2/proj/subproj/api/manifests/v1: unauthorized: HTTP Basic: Access denied"}
```

Here is my deployment gitlab-ci job:

```
docker:
  stage: docker_images
  image: docker:latest
  services:
    - docker:dind
  script:
    - docker login -u "$CI_REGISTRY_USER" -p "$CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD" $CI_REGISTRY
    - docker build -t registry.gitlab.com/proj/subproj/api:v1 -f Dockerfile .
    - docker push registry.gitlab.com/proj/subproj/api:v1
  only:
    - master
  dependencies:
  - build_java

k8s-deploy:
  image: google/cloud-sdk
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - echo "$GOOGLE_KEY" > key.json # Google Cloud service account key
    - gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file key.json
    - gcloud config set compute/zone us-central1-c
    - gcloud config set project proj
    - gcloud config set container/use_client_certificate True
    - gcloud container clusters get-credentials proj-cluster
    - kubectl delete secret registry.gitlab.com  --ignore-not-found
    - kubectl create secret docker-registry registry.gitlab.com --docker-server=https://registry.gitlab.com/v1/ --docker-username="$CI_REGISTRY_USER" --docker-password="$CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD" --docker-email=some@gmail.com
    - kubectl apply -f  cloud-kubernetes.yml
```

and here is cloud-kubernetes.yml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    service.alpha.kubernetes.io/tolerate-unready-endpoints: "true"
  name: proj
  labels:
    app: proj
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer 
  ports:
  - port: 8082
    name: proj
    targetPort: 8082
    nodePort: 32756
  selector:
    app: proj
---    
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: projdeployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: proj
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: projcontainer
        image: registry.gitlab.com/proj/subproj/api:v1
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        env:
          - name: SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE
            value: "cloud"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8082
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: registry.gitlab.com
```

I have followed [this article](https://about.gitlab.com/2016/12/14/continuous-delivery-of-a-spring-boot-application-with-gitlab-ci-and-kubernetes/)

Comment: Are you sure that you created the secret in the same namespace as the deployment?

Comment: For secret i user default namespace(according to kubectl describe secrets)

Comment: And deployments use default too(according to  kubectl get pods --all-namespaces)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is workaround, image could be pushed to google container registry, and then pulled from gcr without security. We can push image to gcr without gcloud cli using [json token file](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication). So `.gitlab-ci.yaml` could look like:

```
docker:
  stage: docker_images
  image: docker:latest
  services:
    - docker:dind
  script:
    - docker login -u "$CI_REGISTRY_USER" -p "$CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD" $CI_REGISTRY
    - docker build -t registry.gitlab.com/proj/subproj/api:v1 -f Dockerfile .
    - docker push registry.gitlab.com/proj/subproj/api:v1
    - docker tag registry.gitlab.com/proj/subproj/api:v1 gcr.io/proj/api:v1
    - docker login -u _json_key -p "$GOOGLE_KEY" https://gcr.io
    - docker push gcr.io/proj/api:v1
  only:
    - master
  dependencies:
  - build_java

k8s-deploy:
  image: google/cloud-sdk
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - echo "$GOOGLE_KEY" > key.json # Google Cloud service account key
    - gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file key.json
    - gcloud config set compute/zone us-central1-c
    - gcloud config set project proj
    - gcloud config set container/use_client_certificate True
    - gcloud container clusters get-credentials proj-cluster
    - kubectl apply -f cloud-kubernetes.yml
```

And image in cloud-kubernetes.yaml should be:

gcr.io/proj/api:v1

Answer (score 2):

You must use `--docker-server=CI_REGISTRY`.
The same as you sue for `docker login -u "$CI_REGISTRY_USER" -p "$CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD" $CI_REGISTRY`.

Also note that your docker secrets must be in the same namespace with Deployment/ReplicaSet/DaemonSet/StatefullSet/Job.

Comment: It was first what i have tried, then i found this [thread](https://forum.gitlab.com/t/docker-login-fails-with-registry-gitlab-com/6208/9), somebody suggested to use v1 url - no result
namespace - default everywhere.

Comment: For me its was namespace, secret was created in default namespace and I was deploying it other namespace