# GKE Cluster can't pull (ErrImagePull) from Gitlab private Registry

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, gitlab, google-kubernetes-engine

I have deployed my image in my gitlab docker repository

When I try to deploy my app on Kubernetes, I get the following error

```
cluster-default-pool-2e5b4771-5z37
  Normal   BackOff    29s (x2 over 30s)  kubelet, gke-gara-cluster-default-pool-2e5b4771-5z37  Back-off pulling image "registry.gitlab.com/gara-project/back-end-micro-services/mconsoleuser:latest"
  Warning  Failed     29s (x2 over 30s)  kubelet, gke-gara-cluster-default-pool-2e5b4771-5z37  Error: ImagePullBackOff
  Normal   Pulling    15s (x2 over 31s)  kubelet, gke-gara-cluster-default-pool-2e5b4771-5z37  pulling image "registry.gitlab.com/gara-project/back-end-micro-services/mconsoleuser:latest"
  Warning  Failed     14s (x2 over 30s)  kubelet, gke-gara-cluster-default-pool-2e5b4771-5z37  Failed to pull image "registry.gitlab.com/gara-project/back-end-micro-services/mconsoleuser:latest": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: Get https://registry.gitlab.com/v2/gara-project/back-end-micro-services/mconsoleuser/manifests/latest: unauthorized: HTTP Basic: Access denied
  Warning  Failed     14s (x2 over 30s)  kubelet, gke-gara-cluster-default-pool-2e5b4771-5z37  Error: ErrImagePull
```

I created a secret with my login and password with the command :

```
kubectl create secret docker-registry registry-gitlab-secrets --docker-server=registry.gitlab.com --docker-username=kosted --docker-password="MY-REAL-PASSWORD" \
--docker-email=mymail@yahoo.fr
```

I added in my deployment

```
imagePullSecrets:
        - name : registry-gitlab-secrets
```

My entire deployment looks like :

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: "{{ include "m-consoleuser.name" . }}-deployment"
  labels:
    app: {{ include "m-consoleuser.name" . }}
    tier: backend
spec:
  replicas: {{ .Values.replicaCount }}
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: {{ include "m-consoleuser.name" . }}
      tier: backend
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: {{ include "m-consoleuser.name" . }}
        tier: backend
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: {{ .Chart.Name }}
          image: "{{ .Values.image.repository }}:{{ .Values.image.tag }}"
          imagePullPolicy: {{ .Values.image.pullPolicy }}
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 9102
              protocol: TCP
          livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /
              port: http
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /
              port: http
          resources:
            {{- toYaml .Values.resources | nindent 12 }}
      {{- with .Values.nodeSelector }}
      nodeSelector:
        {{- toYaml . | nindent 8 }}
      {{- end }}
    {{- with .Values.affinity }}
      affinity:
        {{- toYaml . | nindent 8 }}
    {{- end }}
    {{- with .Values.tolerations }}
      tolerations:
        {{- toYaml . | nindent 8 }}
    {{- end }}
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: registry-gitlab-secrets
```

Still getting the same error. Please how could I do ?

EDIT: I ssh inside one of the node and run docker login registry.gitlab.com with the same credentials as provident during kubectl create secrets. I got login succeeded, and I can pull my image. I don't know why during helm deploy i can't pull the image

Comment: Maybe this help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47246922/kubectl-pull-image-from-gitlab-unauthorized-http-basic-access-denied

Comment: I suspect the error is due to the wrong username and password, so it is good to check that.  `kubectl create secret docker-registry <name> --docker-server=DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER --docker-username=DOCKER_USER --docker-password=DOCKER_PASSWORD --docker-email=DOCKER_EMAIL`

Comment: @danyL username and password is correct because I use the same credentials to clone projects from gitlab

Comment: @Arslanbekov, the link you sent is about ci/cd from gitlab. And the answer they give is to push the image on google cloud repository. It is not really what i'm trying to do.

Comment: btw: Whitespace is missed in that yaml infront of `imagePullSecrets`

Comment: @Nick thanks for you answer. I added whitespace infront of imagePullSecrets, still getting the same issue.